# How to install qmake? Ubuntu x64 17.04

Tags: qmake

I want to compile `keepassx 0.4`. It says I need qmake. I enter `apt-get install qmake` and nothing happens.

Also I did

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cmake qtbase5-dev libqt5x11extras5-dev qttools5-dev qttools5-dev-tools libgcrypt20-dev zlib1g-dev libxi-dev libxtst-dev
```

and also I run all commands from here

https://wiki.qt.io/Install_Qt_5_on_Ubuntu

Nothing help.

Everything I try gives me:

```
qmake: could not exec '/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/qt4/bin/qmake': No such file or directory
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.7/Modules/FindQt4.cmake:1318 (message):
  Found unsuitable Qt version "" from NOTFOUND, this code requires Qt 4.x
Call Stack (most recent call first):
  CMakeLists.txt:59 (FIND_PACKAGE)
```

Please help!

Comment: As noted by the error message, it requires Qt 4.x, not Qt 5. You need to install the qt4 development stack.

Comment: @dobey I copy\pasted a lot of words into the terminal that has `qt4` in them. Will it work? How do I know what I have?